# Why does give me output 2 where i'm used type cast?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm trying to type casting int to float using below code. I'm work before using type cast. But this is not working. Please help me out.

```
int n;
n=5;
n=(float)n/2;
cout<<n<<endl;
```

“I expect the output of 5/2 to be 2.5, but the actual output is 2.”

Comment: `n` is of type `int`. It can only hold an integral value.

Comment: @nafischonchol Think of it this way: `int n` is what you've decided. `n` will be an integer for its whole life. You can throw real numbers at it and ... it'll just ignore the fractions and do the best integer it can from what you gave it. `int pi = 3.1; if(pi==3) ... ` will be true.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I don't have the motivation today. Besides, there's already a good answer.

Comment: @RSahu :-) I just had a feeling that you'd be able to provide something that could be referred to if there wasn't an answer already. I also upvoted the current answer though.

Comment: I couldn't find a prior answer good enough to suggest this as a duplicate - so until someone does, it's an upvote for me.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I'm got my solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I expect the output of 5/2 to be 2.5, but the actual output is 2 ?

To get `2.5` as a result `n` should of `float` type not `int` type, an integer can't hold floating point number like `2.5`.

Try this version

```
int n = 5;
float res = (float)n/2;
```

and print the `res`

Comment: Maybe you should add a comment that a variable's type does not change in C or C++. An `int` remains an `int` even if you assign a `float` or a `char` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter n is an integer number. So, you try to assign to it a float number but he is an integer. You should use another variable of type float or print it.